# Add previous element to current in list then assign to variable - Python 3.5.2

Tags: python

First post on here, I'm stoked!  Okay, so here is the question:  How do I add previous element to current element and then make a new list from those values to add them to matplotlib graph?  Here is an example of my code:

---

```
example_list = [20, 5, 5, -10]

print(example_list) '''first output should be'''
[20, 5, 5, -10]

value1 = (example_list[0])
value2 = (example_list[0] + example_list[1])
value3 = (example_list[0] + example_list[1] + example_list[2])
value4 = (example_list[0] + example_list[1] + example_list[2] + example_list[3])
```

'''I think you can see the point I'm trying to make'''

del example_list[:]

```
example_list.append(value1)
example_list.append(value2)
example_list.append(value3)
example_list.append(value4)

print(example_list)
'''output should be:'''

[20, 25, 30, 20]
```

---

'''This works for hard coding it in, but I want this to happen for hundreds of elements. (when people add to list from my "simple_finance_app" Python script)'''  Thanks for the help!  (P.S. I already have the matplotlib code so no need to add that, however, I it could help others who read this question/answer)

Comment: So your question is how to get cumulative sums up to a specific index, basically?

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean by that? Heh, I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) method for that:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import add

result = list(accumulate(example_list,add))
```

This generates:

```
>>> list(accumulate(example_list,add))
[20, 25, 30, 20]
```

If the function (here `operator.add`) works in *O(n)*, then `accumulate` will work in *O(n)* whereas your hardcoded solution works in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Basically the `accumulate(iterable[,func])` function takes as input an iterable `[x1,x2,...,xn]` and a function `f`, and each iteration it calls `f` on the *accumulator* and the new element. In the first step it emits the first element, and then the accumulator becomes that element. So it basically generates `[x1,f(x1,x2),f(f(x1,x2),x3),...]`. But *without* calculating `f(x1.x2)` each time. It is thus semantically equivalent to:

```
def accumulate(iterable,func): # semantical equivalent of itertools.accumulate
    iterer = iter(iterable)
    try:
        accum = next(iterer)
        while True:
            yield accum
            accum = func(accum,next(iterer))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

but probably less error prone and more efficient.

Comment: Very informative and very accurate to what I needed for my project, thank you Mr. Onsem!  That function seems to be a bit beyond me.  I'm still trying to wrap my head what you said about that specific function you created, but I'll learn it for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You mean `sum` combined with slicing?

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a = sum(li[:1])
b = sum(li[:2])
c = sum(li[:3])
d = sum(li[:4])  # same as sum(li) in this case
```

Or in general:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in range(len(li)):
    print(sum(li[:i + 1]))
# 1
# 3
# 6
# 10
# 15
# 21
# 28
# 36
# 45
```

Comment: I don't like the complexity of this. You are summing up from the first element every time when you don't need to.

Comment: @timgeb Indeed. Since `itertools` provides a builtin solution which I wasn't aware of (see another answer) I won't bother improving this :)

Comment: Hmm, this one seems to work too.  But I want those values set into a variable that I can then use for matplotlib graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla `for` loop solution:

```
>>> example_list = [20, 5, 5, -10]
>>> out = []
>>> sum = 0
>>> for x in example_list:
...     sum += x
...     out.append(sum)
... 
>>> out
[20, 25, 30, 20]
```

Note that repeatedly calling `sum` in a `for` loop/comprehension will result in O(n^2) complexity.